# Using shared library created in a different directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I've created a shared library with library.h and library.cpp. Then wrote a CMakeLists.txt file to build it as a shared library.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test_pro)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_library(test_pro SHARED library.cpp library.h)
```

after building the library, I was able to get a .so file as `/home/user/projects/test_lib/bin/libtest_pro.so`

Then I tried linking the created library to another project in `/home/user/projects/testproject`

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(testproject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

link_directories(
        /home/user/projects/test_lib/bin
)
add_executable(testproject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (testproject test_pro)
```

It successfully builds the testproject (ldd command shows it has linked correctly), but I'm unable to use the library I've created in it.

In the `main.cpp` I've tried,

`#include "library.h"`

`#include "test_pro"`

`#include <test_pro>`

`#include <test_pro/library.h>`

But all the above gave build failures (`fatal error: xxx: No such file or directory`). How do I use this created library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you set `link_directories()` you have to specify `include_directories()`. And it is recommended not to use `link_directories()` at all, instead pass absolute path to the library into `target_link_libraries()`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. That means we have to include the header files of the library to our project? Is there any other way to build the library so that we don't need to include header files via cmake?

Comment: Well, C/C++ works this way. You can copy library headers into every project you are using it in, but that's even worse.

Comment: but there are libraries (if we take gtest) which we only want to define the name in target_link_libraries without including the headers. Does it store headers in system path?

Comment: @prabushitha: gtest is used either via `add_subdirectory(gtest)` or via `find_package(gtest)`. In both cases, when you link with it (`target_link_libraries`), `gtest` is a **CMake library target** with include directories *attached* to it. In your case, you link with your library using path to your *library file*. That file doesn't contain information about include directories. You may adjust your project for being used in the same manner like gtest.